# are there any template engine without scala in play framework [2.x]?

Tags: playframework-2.0, template-engine

I'm an ex php developer and new a junior java developer.

I want to know. Are there any another template engine without scala language in play framework?

I dont want to use scala template engine in play framework.

Thank you.

Comment: i think scala is very complicated. Why do i use two programming languages ? I want to use only java :) by the way, i used smarty template engine(php) and i really liked.

Comment: There is a Groovy Templates module. Take a look at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/Modules.md

Answer (score 4):

Actually you should separate two different things: your main language used for building the project - it can be Java OR Scala OR (Java AND Scala) all belongs to you.

Second thing is templating engine, although there are other possibilities like Groovy mentioned by Franz it's not good option to use them instead of built-in one. The main goal of using Scala templates is its type-safety and compilation for performance.

What's more templating system not always uses the same language as the framework - if you'll compare ie. PHP and Smarty syntax - they fits like a "fist to the nose". So if you stop thinking as "Java vs. Scala" and start "Controller and View" you'll recognize that's nothing wrong about that.

Initial Scala knowledge required for creating templates is less complicated than understanding Smarty, on the other hand as it's still programming language you're able to use all its goodies just directly in the view, which makes it really powerful.